# Hide title in fullscreen (AppCompatActivity)

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide the `title bar` in fullscreen mode. When i try to use `Activity`, the title bar vanishes. But when i use `AppCompatActivity`, it still remains. Any idea why this happens? Should i change something else such as the manifest? Here is the code which i have used to hide the title bar and go fullscreen:

```
public class MoreInfoNotification extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.more_info_notification);
}
```

Thanks. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When using an AppCompatActivity to remove the ActionBar/Title the theme of that activity; specified in the `styles.xml` file must be one of the NoActionBar themes:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I created a new `theme` for the activity `MoreInfoNotification` with parent as the previous activity.

```
<!--Theme for parent activity--> 
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<!--Theme for new activity-->
<style name="MoreOnNotificationTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

There is **NO NEED** to add the following lines in the `MoreInfoNotification` activity:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```